# reopen atom show all last closed files/project

Tags: atom-editor

How can I automatically display all last closed files when reopening Atom, like Sublime Text does? It seems Atom always displays a blank file (or nothing) when opened.

I installed [open-recent](https://atom.io/packages/open-recent), but seems it is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Atom preferences, under the "Core" section, you should find this option. It sounds like you want it to be checked.

> **Restore Previous Windows On Start**
>
> When checked restores the last state of all Atom windows when started from the icon or `atom` by itself from the command line; otherwise a blank environment is loaded.

---

From your question text (the phrase "last *closed* files") and your note in the comments, it seems you are expecting Atom to restore windows you closed *before* the application quit. That is not how it will normally behave, and that is pretty typical of multi-window macOS applications.

In most macOS applications, windows that were open *at the time the application quit* will be automatically reopened. This can be disabled in many apps, but that is usually the default behavior.

If you close the window *before* quitting, using the red "close" button in the title bar, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, then most applications (including Atom) will assume that was intentional, and that you no longer wish that window to be open.

Comment: Thanks, I see. And I found maybe there is a bug for Atom on Mac. When you click "Quit" from the menu bar or use shortcut cmd+q, they are all fine. But when you click left top close icon, it will show an untitled tag when reopen.

Comment: @Richard I updated my answer with a bit more about the window reopening behavior in macOS.